# Efficient way to place orphaned element(s) at top/beginning using CSS flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

When you use flexbox wrap to create a grid and you have a last row with less elements than the previous rows the default behaviour of "orphaned" elements with `flex: 1` is to stretch horizontally to fill the width - making the elements larger than previous rows. I want the same behaviour except I want the larger items to appear in the top row rather than the bottom row.

I've come up with a solution (shown below) but it doesn't scale well and it feels like a bad hack. Is there a better (more elegant) way to achieve this layout? The solution needs to handle dynamic content; ie, I won't know the number of elements beforehand and I need to maintain the source ordering.

It should look like this:

[image: flex orphans at top]

```
ul#subcategory_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(1) {order: 30}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(2) {order: 29}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(3) {order: 28}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(4) {order: 27}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(5) {order: 26}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(6) {order: 25}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(7) {order: 24}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(8) {order: 23}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(9) {order: 22}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(10) {order: 21}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(11) {order: 20}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(12) {order: 19}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(13) {order: 18}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(14) {order: 17}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(15) {order: 16}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(16) {order: 15}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(17) {order: 14}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(18) {order: 13}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(19) {order: 12}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(20) {order: 11}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(21) {order: 10}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(22) {order: 9}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(23) {order: 8}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(24) {order: 7}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(25) {order: 6}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(26) {order: 5}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(27) {order: 4}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(28) {order: 3}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(29) {order: 2}
ul#subcategory_list li:nth-child(30) {order: 1}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to get rid of the `nth-child` CSS rule listing, there is no 1-liner that does that. If you generate the items dynamically, you could add the `order` property inline, and if you don't know in advance how many items, you could start from a value that you for sure never exceed, i.e. 1000 and then go downwards. If this is a viable option, I can post that as an answer.

Comment: Post it as an answer. I do have access to the server-side generation so inline code is a good option that I'd overlooked (however less/sass are not part of my deployment so they don't count). Your answer solves the stylesheet clutter and scalability issues which is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get rid of the `nth-child` CSS rule listing, there is no 1-liner that does that.

If you generate the items dynamically, you could add the `order` property inline, and if you don't know in advance how many items, you could start from a value that you for sure never exceed, i.e. 1000 and then go downwards.

Stack snippet

```css
ul#subcategory_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

ul#subcategory_list li {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul id="subcategory_list">
  <li style="order: 1000">1</li>
  <li style="order: 999">2</li>
  <li style="order: 998">3</li>
  <li style="order: 997">4</li>
  <li style="order: 996">5</li>
  <li style="order: 995">6</li>
</ul>
```