# Flexbox full reverse

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to make something like a news list (not really, but it makes sense when explained like this) of unknown number of items. I'd like to reverse it, so if I add one at the and, it will appear as the first one. I tried using flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; flex-direction: row-reverse` (with shorthand `flex-flow`).

```css
#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 270px;
}

.report {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">2 mins old</div>
  <div class="report">The new one</div>
</div>
```

However, as you see above, the first (last in HTML) item is alone on the "first" row. Can I fix this or how else can I achieve this (ideally without JS)?

Comment: Would it be plausible to insert your new data in the desired order before render?

Comment: The simplest solution of all would be to reverse the order of elements. Post the newest entries first, not last. No need for JS. No CSS hacks. Just clean, simple and easy to maintain code. https://jsfiddle.net/a2d0x3rg/1/

Comment: I think I agree with Michael, if you are dynamically loading these elements you can just reverse them server-side or with your frontend framework before rending.  Or if it's static just reverse manually.  Seems like the easiest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Because this uses `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, the last element in the DOM order is still treated by flexbox as the last element to "fit in" to the flexbox schema.  **The `wrap-reverse` just means that elements are wrapped above previous ones instead of below.**  Basically, to have the first row filled with non "flex-growed" items with pure CSS is not possible.  The below solution works because flex-grow allows the last element to take up the empty space.

Another option would be to make sure you always have the proper number of elements to make sure that the last (rendered on top) line is always full, like so:

```css
#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 270px;
}

.report {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">2 mins old</div>
  <div class="report">The new one</div>
</div>
```

**Original Answer**

You have to specify a `flex` property on the children reports:

```css
#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 270px;
}

.report {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">2 mins old</div>
  <div class="report">The new one</div>
</div>
```

Etc

Comment: Woow! That's really good, but sadly it's not what I want in my case. That wasn't specified in the question, but I'm displaying squares with images, so this is out of the question... See that website: https://e-vo-linka.cz

Comment: You will have to adjust the flex shrink, grow, and basis properties as well as width and height to get it how you like.

Comment: Also because you are using `wrap-reverse`, it's like having the entire flex block upside down.  This is why you end up with "the new one" on top by itself.

Comment: @M.Volf Updated my answer.  @LGSon's anwer using the `order` property is also good if you can specify the order attribute for each element.

Answer (score 2):

With the given markup, w/o using script, one could make use of the `order` property.

Combined with an *unknown* amount of items, still will need to be based on a *max* number of items, where I here started for up to 100.

Stack snippet

```css
#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 270px;
}

.report {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}

.report:nth-child(1) { order: 100; }
.report:nth-child(2) { order:  99; }
.report:nth-child(3) { order:  98; }
.report:nth-child(4) { order:  97; }
.report:nth-child(5) { order:  96; }
.report:nth-child(6) { order:  95; }
.report:nth-child(7) { order:  94; }
.report:nth-child(8) { order:  93; }
.report:nth-child(9) { order:  92; }
/*  and so on...  */
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">Other report</div>
  <div class="report">2 mins old</div>
  <div class="report">The new one</div>
</div>
```

---

Another option could be, if these elements are rendered dynamically server/client side, to add the `order` property inline, as suggested in this answer of mine:

- [Efficient way to place orphaned element(s) at top/beginning using CSS flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804750/efficient-way-to-place-orphaned-elements-at-top-beginning-using-css-flexbox/46805044#46805044)

With this you could start at e.g. `order: 10000`, save some CSS coding and count down from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here how I see it lies in the fact that in your own example the last item is already centered on the last line. Is it supposed to be? Usually you want it to be aligned to the left side of the screen, right?

If that's correct, the only non-js way to fix it I know is to add hidden zero-height placeholders. It is described somewhere here on stackoverflow.

When you don't know how many placeholders  to add, you can add any safe number, because they have 0 height they don't affect to visual representation.

Now if we adapt this technique to the example it turns out to be like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/4L3actqd/

```
#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 270px;

  & > .hidden-f { display: none; }
  & > .hidden-e { display: block; }

  &.reversed {
    flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;    

    & > .hidden-f { display: block; }
    & > .hidden-e { display: none; }
  }
}

.report {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}

.hidden-e, .hidden-f {
  width: 70px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 5px;  
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work when reversed, as you can see here, where one items is removed: https://jsfiddle.net/4L3actqd/2/

Comment: Wow! Unfortunately :-( The login behind this flex reverse rules is quire weird. They I can't see a way but setting flex order to children